# FosUserBundle how to ajax login

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

This is my first SF2 project, while this framework is quite easy to learn (I come from codeIgniter), there is still advanced uses I'm not fluent with.

Here's the thing. Fos userBundle is installed, working fine, I've override forms for login, register, check out.

I want to login using ajax, and... I'm totally lost. I believe I should overload SecurityController that way:

```
<?php
namespace BioMeta\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function checkAction()
    {
        die('pooh');
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Is your user bundle setup so that its the child bundle of the FOS\UserBundle?

```
//src/BioMeta/UserBundle/BioMetaUserBundle.php

public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
}
```

Have a look at the documentation on how to override the controllers: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

It looks like you are trying to override the `checkAction`. The check action isnt handled by the FOSUserBundle it is handled directly by Symfony. It is only in there to remind you to make sure the login path is setup currectly.

You should be able to override any of the other functions in that controller.

**Make sure that you clear your development cache after overriding the files**

Comment: Yes ! (overloading forms works just fine), I followed the doc, I don't understand why it's not working...
And yes, cache:clear is the first thin I tried :p

Comment: It probably is working you just cant change the checkAction because it doesnt actually get called. Symfony handles that check.